# Android: Credentials always sent with CORS requests?

Tags: android, credentials, xmlhttprequest, cors

When sending CORS requests (XHR API), the credentials should not be sent implicitly ([W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)). This should only when the option withCredentials is set to true.

Apparently Android does not take this rule into account?

An example CORS system can be found [here](http://www.wiro.be/nieuwesite/personel/cors). This example seems to work for Mozilla (Firefox & Fennec), Google Chrome and Safari, but not for the Android browser.

Can anyone confirm this flaw?

Grtz,
Maarten

Comment: Just curious, does it work if you explicitly set withCredentials to false?  Or is withCredentials ignored entirely?

Comment: withCredentials is ignored entirely... but the answer of the server (Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true or false) is taken into account, depending on the withCredentials value. Strange behavior if u ask me.